# Swift -AVPlayer' KVO in cell's parent vc causing Xcode to freeze

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, avplayer, key-value-observing

I have a cell that takes up the entire screen so there is only 1 visible cell at a time. Inside the cell I have an AVPlayer. Inside the cell's parent vc I have a KVO observer that listens to the `"timeControlStatus"`. When the player stops playing I call a function `stopVideo()` inside the cell to stop the player and either show a replay button or a play button etc.

3 problems:

1- When the video stops/reaches end if I don't use DispatchQueue inside the KVO the app crashes when the cell's function is called.

2- When the video stops and I do use DispatchQueue inside the KVO it's observer keeps observing and Xcode freezes (no crash). There is a print statement inside the KVO that prints indefinitely and that's why Xcode freezes. The only way to stop it is to kill Xcode otherwise the beachball of death keeps spinning.

3- In the KVO I tried to use a notification to send to the cell in place of calling the `cell.stopVideo()` function but the function inside the cell never runs.

**How can i fix this issue?**

It should be noted that outside of the KVO not working everything else works fine. I have a periodic time observer that runs perfectly for every cell whenever I scroll, the videos load fine, and when I press the cell stop/play the video it all works fine.

cell:

```
protocol MyCellDelegate: class {
    func sendBackPlayerAndIndexPath(_ player: AVPlayer?, currentIndexPath: IndexPath?)
}

var player: AVPlayer?
var indexPath: IndexPath?

var playerItem: AVPlayerItem? { 
    didSet {
         // add playerItem to player
         delegate?.sendBackPlayerAndIndexPath(player, indexPath)
    }
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    player = AVPlayer()
    // set everything else relating to the player   
}

// both get initialized in cellForItem
var delegate: MyCellDelegate?
var myModel: MyModel? {
     didSet {
          let url = URL(string: myModel!.videUrlStr!)
          asset = AVAsset(url: url)
          playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset, automaticallyLoadedAssetKeys: ["playable"])
     }
}

// tried using this with NotificationCenter but it didn't trigger from parent vc
@objc public func playVideo() {
    if !player?.isPlaying {
       player?.play()
    }
    // depending on certain conditions show a mute button, etc
}

// tried using this with NotificationCenter but it didn't trigger from parent vc
@objc public func stopVideo() {
    player?.pause()
    // depending on certain conditions show a reload button or a play button etc
}
```

parent vc

```
MyVC: ViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

var player: AVPlayer?
var currentIndexPath: IndexPath?
var isObserving = false

func sendBackPlayerAndIndexPath(_ player: AVPlayer?, currentIndexPath: IndexPath?) {

    if isObserving {
        self.player?.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", context: nil)
        self.player?.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "timeControlStatus", context: nil)
    }

    guard let p = player, let i = currentIndexPath else { return }

    self.player = p
    self.currentIndexPath = i

    isObserving = true
    self.player?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options: [.old, .new], context: nil)
    self.player?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "timeControlStatus", options: [.old, .new], context: nil)
}

// If I don't use DispatchQueue below the app crashes
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

    if object as AnyObject? === player {
        if keyPath == "status" {
            if player?.status == .readyToPlay {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                        self?.playVideoInCell()
                    }
                }
            }
        } else if keyPath == "timeControlStatus" {

            if player?.timeControlStatus == .playing {
                DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                    self?.playVideoInCell()
                }

            } else {

                print("3. Player is Not Playing *** ONCE STOPPED THIS PRINTS FOREVER and Xcode freezes but doesn't crash.\n")
                DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                    self?.stopVideoInCell()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func playVideoInCell() {
    guard let indexPath = currentIndexPath else { return }
    guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? MyCell else { return }

    cell.playVideo()
    // also tried sending a NotificationCenter message to the cell but it didn't trigger
}

func stopVideoInCell() {
    guard let indexPath = currentIndexPath else { return }
    guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? MyCell else { return }

    cell.stopVideo()
    // also tried sending a NotificationCenter message to the cell but it didn't trigger
}
```

In the comments @matt asked for the crash log (only occurs when not using DispatchQueue inside the KVO). I have zombies enabled and it didn't give me any info. The crash happens instantaneously and then just goes blank. It doesn't give me any info. I had to quickly take a screen shot just to get the pic otherwise it disappears right after the crash.

[image]

[image]

Inside the KVO, the 3rd one that prints forever, I removed the DispatchQueue and just added the `stopVideoInCell()` function. When the function calls the cell's `stopVideo()` function,  **player?.pause** briefly gets a **EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16b01ff0)** crash.

[image]

The app then terminates. Inside the console the only thing that is printed is:

> Message from debugger: The LLDB RPC server has crashed. The crash log
>   is located in ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports and has a prefix
>   'lldb-rpc-server'. Please file a bug and attach the most recent crash
>   log

When I go to terminal and see what prints out the only thing I get is a bunch of `lldb-rpc-server_2020-06-14-155514_myMacName.crash` statements from all the days I ran into this crash.

When using DispatchQueue this doesn't occur and the video does stop but of course that print statement inside the KVO runs forever and Xcode freezes.

Comment: What's the crash log when the app crashes?

Comment: Also you do know that you should really not be using `observeValue(forKeyPath)` any more, right? That might not be relevant but it's really a crummy method; the Swift overlay method is way better, calling it for you in a controlled context and dealing with unregistration etc.

Comment: @matt I never knew I shouldn't use it anymore. I actually learned about it in your book but that was iOS 10 (I still reference the book :). There aren't any warning about it being deprecated for iOS 13

Comment: LOL. No, it isn't deprecated, but `observe(_:options:changeHandler:)` is a way better front for it.

Comment: You're saying the app crashes but nothing at all is printed in the Console?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that. I'll look around on SO and see what I can find then change. Why is the old version crummy, it worked for yrs? Do you think that could possibly be the issue? Btw if I comment out the DispatchQueue, everything works fine even though at that point it's useless to use the kvo observers. The problem is definitely happening because of them.

Comment: "There is a print statement inside the KVO that prints indefinitely" Yeah, that sounds like a recursion. I think I see it too: you are observing the status, and inside the observer method you change the status, so you recurse infinitely. Eventually I presume you would stack overflow if you let it go on long enough.

Comment: This is the message: **Message from debugger: The LLDB RPC server has crashed. The crash log is located in ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports and has a prefix 'lldb-rpc-server'. Please file a bug and attach the most recent crash log.**

Comment: @matt I added some more info at the bottom of the photo. Where do you see the recursion at?

Comment: Wow so what's crashing is LLDB itself, cool. You should report that to Apple, as they request.

Comment: oh shoot, it sounds like it's out of my control. I'll file a radar but in the mean time what should I do? Should I switch the the updated observer method that you mentioned earlier? If that doesn't work do you have any recommendations?

Comment: My thought was: You observe the status, in the observer you start playing, that changes the status which is what you are observing...?

Comment: I'm using the latest Xcode 11.5, strange that lldb crash would occur

Comment: interesting recursion theory. Maybe that is the reason it prints forever. I'm going to try the updated method you suggested and see what happens. I'll message you later today with the results. Thanks and enjoy your day!

Comment: @matt I just tried **observe(_:options:changeHandler:)** and no dice, same recursion issue. I then changed **player?.observe(\.status...)** to **player?.observe(\.currentItem?.status...)** and same recursion issue. Thanks for the help and advice. Cheers!!!

Comment: Yes, I never expected it to break the recursion. _You_ need to break it.

Comment: @matt the only thing I can think of is to add a Boolean. Iffy try it and get back to you

Comment: Well it seems to me you just need to unregister (i.e. stop observing). I mean, for example, you observe `timeControlStatus` and if it is not playing, you say `stop`. Well, then the status is now not playing and you are still observing. So the status is not playing _again_, and again and again and again... Recursion. To what end? I don't even understand what the point is _supposed_ to be.

Comment: because the person can press the cell to pause the video then press it again to unpause it. I’ll have to keep registering on and off for both events.

Comment: @matt you was right about the new kvos. I don’t know if they perform better but I do know they are much easier to setup, destroy, maintain/visually look at. I have a couple of different vcs that use has a player I switched them all over to use the new ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, in your property observer, you are making a change in the property that you are observing. That is a vicious circle, an infinite recursion; Xcode displays this by freezing your app until ultimately you crash with (oh, the irony) a stack overflow.

Let's take a simpler, self-contained example. We have a UISwitch in the interface. It's On. If the user switches it Off, we want to detect that and switch it back to On. The example is a silly way to do this, but it perfectly illustrates the issue you are facing:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var theSwitch: UISwitch!
    class SwitchHelper: NSObject {
        @objc dynamic var switchState : Bool = true
    }
    let switchHelper = SwitchHelper()
    var observer: NSKeyValueObservation!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.observer = self.switchHelper.observe(\.switchState, options: .new) { 
            helper, change in
            self.theSwitch.isOn.toggle()
            self.theSwitch.sendActions(for: .valueChanged)
        }
    }
    @IBAction func doSwitch(_ sender: Any) {
        self.switchHelper.switchState = (sender as! UISwitch).isOn
    }
}
```

What's going to happen? The user turns the switch Off. We are observing that, as `switchState`; in response, we switch the switch back to On and call `sendActions`. And `sendActions` changes `switchState`. But we are still in the middle of the code that observes `switchState`! So we do it again and it happens again. And again and it happens again. Infinite loop...

How would you get out of this? You need to break the recursion somehow. I can think of two obvious ways. One is to think to yourself, "Well, I only care about a switch from On to Off. I don't care about the other way." Assuming that's true, you can solve the problem with a simple `if`, rather like the solution you elected to use:

```
    self.observer = self.switchHelper.observe(\.switchState, options: .new) {
        helper, change in
        if let val = change.newValue, !val {
            self.theSwitch.isOn.toggle()
            self.theSwitch.sendActions(for: .valueChanged)
        }
    }
```

A more elaborate solution, which I like to use sometimes, is to *stop observing* when the observer is triggered, make whatever the change is, and then start observing again. You have to plan ahead a little to implement that, but it's sometimes worth it:

```
var observer: NSKeyValueObservation!
func startObserving() {
    self.observer = self.switchHelper.observe(\.switchState, options: .new) {
        helper, change in
        self.observer?.invalidate()
        self.observer = nil
        self.theSwitch.isOn.toggle()
        self.theSwitch.sendActions(for: .valueChanged)
        self.startObserving()
    }
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.startObserving()
}
```

That *looks* recursive, because `startObserving` calls itself, but it isn't really, because what it does when it is called is to *configure* the observation; the code in the inner curly braces doesn't *run* until we get an observed change.

(In real life, I would probably make the NSKeyValueObservation a local variable in that configuration. But that's just an additional bit of elegance, not essential to the point of the example.)

Comment: "(oh the irony), a stack overflow", lmaoooo. Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this using a `Boolean`. It's not the most elegant answer but it works. If someone can come up with a better answer I'll accept it. It doesn't make sense what's going because of what I put under **more**:

answer:

```
var isPlayerStopped = false

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

    if object as AnyObject? === player {
        if keyPath == "status" {
            if player?.status == .readyToPlay {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                        self?.playVideoInCell()
                    }
                }
            }
        } else if keyPath == "timeControlStatus" {

            if player?.timeControlStatus == .playing {
                DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                    self?.playVideoInCell()
                }

            } else {

                if isPlayerStopped { return }

                print("3. Player is Not Playing *** NOW THIS ONLY PRINTS ONCE.\n")
                DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                    self?.stopVideoInCell()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func playVideoInCell() {
    guard let indexPath = currentIndexPath else { return }
    guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? MyCell else { return }

    isPlayerStopped = false

    cell.playVideo()
}

func stopVideoInCell() {
    guard let indexPath = currentIndexPath else { return }
    guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? MyCell else { return }

    isPlayerStopped = true

    cell.stopVideo()
}
```

**more**:

If I completely remove the DispatchQueues and the functions inside of them and use just print statements, the print statement that prints indefinitely `print("3. Player is Not Playing... \n")` only prints twice, it no longer prints indefinitely so I don't know what's going on with this.

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

    if object as AnyObject? === player {
        if keyPath == "status" {
            if player?.status == .readyToPlay {
                print("1. Player is Playing\n")
            }
        } else if keyPath == "timeControlStatus" {

            if player?.timeControlStatus == .playing {
                print("2. Player is Playing\n")

            } else {
                print("3. Player is Not Playing... \n")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is the sort of thing I meant by breaking the recursion. Don't do anything in the property observer that would, itself, trigger a change in the observed property.

Comment: @matt thanks. One thing I can’t understand though. Why when I add this code with print statements (no bool) doesn’t the recursion still occur? No matter what that 3rd print statement should still print forever.

Comment: Because you didn't say `stop`. That was what was triggering the recursion. I'll add an answer that explains a little better.