# Prevent cellForItem running again after refresh control snaps back to place

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collectionView without a refresh control but I do allow it to bounce.

```
lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView  = {

    // insatiate the cv, its frame is the entire device w/h
    collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
    collectionView.refreshControl = nil
    collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true

    return collectionView
}()
```

On the very first cell, after `cellForItemAt indexPath` runs and the cell has its content, if I pull the cv down, as if refreshing, it bounces back up. Once it bounces back up and hits the top of the screen (its original location), `cellForItemAt indexPath` runs all over again. I have some content inside the cell that is getting reset because the `cellForItemAt indexPath` runs again.

This only happens with the first cell, how can I prevent this?

Comment: You should be prepared for `cellForItemAt` to run at any time. Cells are just views. They shouldn't maintain their own state. You need to ensure that the appropriate view and state is returned each time `cellForItemAt` is called.

Comment: So I need to save the cell’s state once refresh begins, and once it ends if cellForItem gets called again I need to update it with the saved state? I can always add a refresh control

Comment: Not really. The state should be in your model. There shouldn't be any state maintained only in your cell that you need to save.  Maybe you could explain more what the state is that you need to maintain.

Comment: There is a video  inside the cell and a uislider that tracks its progress (maintained by a periodic time observer inside the parent vc, not the cell). Once I pull down the video plays fine and no interruptions but the slider resets and no longer tracks the video current time. The cells are the screen size so there is only 1 cell/video on the screen at a time. Every time cellForItem runs it assumes a new video (via the model) is going to play and using a delegate method to the parent it resets the slider. The slider/periodic time observer is confused on the refresh snap back

Comment: So this is one case where you probably do need to track the state before and after refresh. You would need to save the currently playing data and not reset the video in cellforItem.

Comment: But that's the odd thing, I have **collectionView.refreshControl = nil** so there shouldn't be a refresh at all. It's the snapback after the pull down that makes cellForItem run again. How do I prevent cellForItem from running (so the video doesn't reset) after that snapback is what I can't figure out. Btw the video plays continusly as if nothing happened. It's only the periodic time observer. This is separate question I asked about another issue but it's my exact setup that I'm using now https://stackoverflow.com/q/62377105/4833705

Comment: Since you have full screen cells and the view detected that the cell moved (partially) offscreen it seems it is being invalidated and re-fetched.  You can't really prevent it from running since you don't control when data source methods are called. You could disable the vertical bounce. You need to look into why the time observer is getting messed up.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help. I’ll investigate the time observer further. Enjoy your day!

Comment: You are welcome. Looking at your other code I would probably try and refactor things so that you had an object that encapsulates the video and acts as the observer rather than trying to have a single observer in your view controller. Your model would be a collection of these objects

Comment: So the object would have the time observer inside of it?

Comment: Yes. It it could use delegation back to the view controller

Comment: ok Ill try it and see what I can do. If I run into problems I'll post another question. Cheers!

Comment: @Paulw11 hope it's not too late for your advice but I found the problem which is actually 2 problems. I added this print statement to 'cellForItem': **print(indexPath)**. The cells are full screen, when I'm on the first cell and pull down as if refreshing, when it snaps back it'll print [0, 1], for some reason it thinks I'm scrolling to the next cell. If I'm on the next cell and partially scroll, even just a little the same print statement will print the next cell. eg If I'm on [0,2] and scroll up a little it's print [0,3] and if I scroll down a little [0,1] even though I'm still on [0,2].

Comment: Sounds right. The collection view thinks that a scroll is likely so it gets the next cell ready

Comment: I have paging enabled though, shouldn't it wait for the page to be fully visible?

Comment: No. It does what it does to keep things scrolling nicely. As I said in my first comment the data source method can be called at any time.  Your code needs to handle that